# Keeping windows in the foreground while operating on others? (i.e., not changing windows' focus)

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, window-management

Is there a way of keeping in the foreground windows while I operating on others?

I am using now XUbuntu. However, I am interested also in canonical Ubuntu.

The trick was working on XUbuntu 16.04 (One of my colleagues did it for me on my old laptop and now I have no idea about the keywords to look for to replicate the behavior). Now I am using XUbuntu 18.04 and 20.04 on the two workstations I have.

Comment: If you right-click on the top border of the window, don't you have an option to "Always on top..", "Always below.." & loads of other options?   You didn't give any release details...

Comment: updating the question

Comment: One simple way is to use like window manager. Resize and keep the window aside.

Comment: Question is not much more clear if you ask me. As you ask it, checking the "always to top" option will keep a window in front even if another one is active.

Comment: @vanadium, in your way, I should always repeat the operation. I wanted a default behaviour. I found the option I was looking for playin with the option in `windows manager`. I am going to post it as answer. Thank you for the hints

Comment: I was thinking in that direction, but found the question very unclear. You probably should have elaborated a bit more. In standard Ubuntu, one can change such behaviour in Gnome Tweaks, Window tab: "Click on focus", "Focus on hover" and "Secondary-click" are the available options.

Comment: The problem is exactly that, sometimes, you do not know the right keywords to find the solution you are looking for (i.e., "focus"). 
I did my best to explain. Thanks to the suggestions in the comments, I arrived at the solution in the answer. You can post the solution for the standard Ubuntu distributions based on Gnome. I will vote up, it is more than useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the option in -> `Window Manager` -> `Focus` -> desable the option `Automatically give focus to newly created windows`. Following a screenshot for more details:

[image]

The solution works for Xubuntu (version >= 16.04) but also can gives some useful keywords for other linux-based distribution